# RemoteObjectManager не обновляет количество меток в кластере при увеличении/уменьшении карты (zoom)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, cluster

При первой загрузке страницы RemoteObjectManager корректно показывает количество меток в кластере (допустим кластер из 10 меток).
При zoom соответственно кластер распадается на метки, на карте показывается 10 меток. Но также и остается сам кластер с цифрой 10.
С сервера приходит корректный ответ, в котором уже нет кластера на 10 меток. RemoteObjectManager где то кеширует данные о кол-ве меток в кластере. Как их обновить или отключить этот кеш, кто нибудь сталкивался?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже разобрался. Нужна уникальность id, в том числе, для каждого зума.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]